# Xamarin Forms - How to get the correct time in DatePicker and TimePicker?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the correct format for my DatePicker and TimePicker in Xamarin Forms.

I need to get the correct Date and Time in the following format:

> 12/5/2020 04:12:34 PM

But I keep getting it in this format:

> 12/5/2020 12:00:00 AM 17:31:23.2153540

I want to be able to select the date and time for the due date and get it displayed in the correct format.

Here is my code:

> In my xaml file:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dueDatePicker" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" Format="MMM dd yyyy" MinimumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
<TimePicker x:Name="dueTimePicker" HorizontalOptions="End" />
```

> In my xaml cs file, I am using this code, but it is displaying in the
> wrong format:

```
dueDatePicker.Date.ToString() + " " + dueTimePicker.Time.ToString();
```

Thank you.

Comment: if you just use `ToString` without specifying a format, it will use the standard format for your locale.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the format :`12/5/2020 04:12:34 PM`, you need to add `Format` for `TimePicker` first.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dueDatePicker"
            Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}"
            Format="MMM dd yyyy"
            MinimumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
<TimePicker x:Name="dueTimePicker"
            Format="HH:mm:ss"
            HorizontalOptions="End" />
```

Then `TimePicker` will show the format from `Xaml`, however `DatePicker` need to use another format will show the wanted effect.

Code as follows:

```
if(dueTimePicker.Time.Hours > 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("time is : " + dueDatePicker.Date.ToString("MM/d/yyyy") + dueTimePicker.Time.ToString() + " PM ");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("time is : " + dueDatePicker.Date.ToString("MM/d/yyyy")  + dueTimePicker.Time.ToString() + " AM ");
}
```

The **Console** output is:

> 09-29 13:51:41.771 I/mono-stdout(11803): time is : 09/29/2020 05:00:00 AM
> 09-29 13:51:59.149 I/mono-stdout(11803): time is : 09/29/2020 17:00:00 PM